How to restore lost Eclipse preferences?
On restart of my Ubuntu virtual machine, after opening eclipse, my preferences are lost and eclipse doesn't show my projects anymore, this happened 3 times over 30 restarts.
Cannot determine URI for '/myproject/myfile'.

I can import the project again and this solves that issue, but all my preferences (e.g. content assist) are lost.
Can I restore all my preferences in some smart way instead of manually setting them again?
At first I thought this was caused by turning off the virtual machine abruptly, but this time I closed eclipse and then turned off from inside the virtual machine giving time to save everything.

You can export the preferences to a file using "File > Export..." select "General > Preferences". But it sounds like your workspace .metadata folder is being messed up by something. What version of Eclipse is this? Does it happen with the latest Eclipse 2024-06. (2024-09 will be released very soon)

I'm using 2023-12 maybe I should upgrade and back up my preferences for next time? Thank you
